# WordPress, Apache, MySQL, and Mac

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, macos, apache

I tried setting up WordPress on a Mac, I got Apache running, PHP is up and going and MySQL is running. I put WordPress in `library/webserver/documents` and I visit `localhost/wordpress/wp-admin` to do the install, and get an error establishing database connection.

So I check the database information and password and database name. Everything is correct down to the last syllable in the password, name and database name....

Why am I getting this? I have set up WordPress on Ubuntu and Windows without any issue, but why does a Mac present a problem?

With wp_debug on, it states my password is wrong. I have tried logging into MySQL with the password given and the user name - it works... so that is clearly not wrong...

Comment: Mac bundled Apache is not quite good for dev, better go with MAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: MAMP disk location]

If you're using [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP), make sure that the disk location of the virtual host is correctly configured. I.e., pointing to library/webserver/documents.